# Should I mark assemblies with NeutralResourcesLanguage attribute if I'm not using ResourceManager to retrieve the resources in my application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance, resourcemanager

I'm using custom resource manager in my application. I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385967.aspx) that adding this attribute can improve application performance, but I wonder if it can affect performance even if I don't use ResourceManager?